# What does a scalar field correspond to?

Tags: field-theory, quantum-spin

For spinor fields, the spinorial part tells us the spin state of a particle (whether it is spin up or down). For vector fields, the vector part tells us the polarization state of a vector boson (like a photon). But for scalar fields, what does the “scalar” part actually correspond to? I know that the known scalar field is the Higgs Field, which describes masses of particles, but what would the particular scalar value relate to?

Comment: No further Lorentz features--but the Higgs field has weak isospin and hypercharge properties, as well. The field is just the minimal, pared down model: it merely creates or destroys scalar particles.

Comment: Well you know that a scalar field is one that associates a _number_ (scalar) to each point in a spacetime and the Higgs field is a spin _zero_ field. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @josephh I know that, but what is the meaning of the particular number? Does it correspond to anything physical? For example the spinor for a spinor field corresponds to whether or not a particle will be deflected upward or downward in the S-G experiment. Is there an analog for the scalar?

Comment: I'm not sure what additional information you need. The higgs field has a value of about 246 GeV and the higgs boson has a mass about 125 GeV. It's a spinless field. The Higgs boson does not interact electromagnetically. It does not interact with any massless particles at all, like the photon or gluon. Again, the physical attributes to it in terms of spin, is that it has zero spin. Like you said, fermionic and bosonic fields have particular spin characteristics, and the higgs field has none, setting it apart from the rest. That's what it means physically. Of course it also has zero charge.